# aws elasticsearch getting signature error on post request

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

Got a 403 signature error , when using the below fetch function:

```
    function elasticsearchFetch(AWS, elasticsearchDomain, endpointPath, options = {}, region = process.env.AWS_REGION) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const { body, method = 'GET' } = options;
    const endpoint = new AWS.Endpoint(elasticsearchDomain);
    const request = new AWS.HttpRequest(endpoint, region);
    request.method = method;
    request.path += endpointPath;
    request.headers.host = elasticsearchDomain;
    if (body) {
      request.body = body;
      request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
      request.headers['Content-Length'] = request.body.length;
    }
    const credentials = new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS');
    const signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(request, 'es');
    signer.addAuthorization(credentials, new Date());
    const client = new AWS.HttpClient();
    client.handleRequest(request, null, (res) => {
      let chunks = '';
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        chunks += chunk;
      });
      res.on('end', () => {
        if (res.statusCode !== 201) console.log('Got these options STATUSCODE', JSON.stringify(options, false, 2));
        return resolve({ statusCode: res.statusCode, body: chunks });
      });
    }, (error) => {
      console.log('Got these options ERROR', JSON.stringify(options, false, 2));
      return reject(error);
    });
  });
}
```

This is the options used for the request in above function :

```
{
    "method": "POST",
    "body": "{\"prefix\":\"image_233/ArtService/articles-0/GB/ART-60297885/\",\"id\":\"ART-60297885\",\"retailUnit\":\"GB\",\"commercial\":{\"name\":{\"en-GB\":\"FÖRBÄTTRA\"}},\"schemaType\":\"product\",\"productType\":\"ART\"}"
}
```

and got this error :

```
{
    "statusCode": 403,
    "body": "{\"message\":\"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.\"}"
}
```

This is the endpoint : `233/_doc/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your `Content-Length` header is incorrect, causing the signature mismatch.

- Your payload includes the string `FÖRBÄTTRA`, which has two double-byte characters.
- You're setting the `Content-Length` to `request.body.length`, which comes to 186.
- While this *is* the number of characters in the body, it is *not* the number of bytes in the body (188).

---

To calculate the `Content-Length`, use `Buffer.byteLength(request.body)`.  For a `POST` request like this, you can even remove that line of code altogether, and the request will succeed.

```
  // Content-Length is only needed for DELETE requests that include a request
  // body, but including it for all requests doesn't seem to hurt anything.
  request.headers['Content-Length'] = Buffer.byteLength(request.body);
```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-request-signing.html#es-request-signing-node

Comment: wow how great you are! I was 3 days with that problem and did not get the solution!
Thank you very much, you saved my life!

Answer (score 0):

By the way, why not use `elasticsearch` client for nodejs to communicate with elasticsearch rather than writing your own logic. You can consider using `http-aws-es` which does the request signing part for you. The code will look like

```
const { Client } = require("elasticsearch");
const esConnectionClass = require("http-aws-es");

const elasticsearchConfig = {
  host: "somePath",
  connectionClass: esConnectionClass
};

const nativeClient = new Client(elasticsearchConfig);

const result = await nativeClient.search({});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashish , we were already using this logic for our bulk operations with es and we would like to resolve the issue than going to another solution